# Div sidebar width, positioning, padding problems on MacBook Pro Chrome, only

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

My WordPress static page looks like it's supposed to look on every browser and machine I have tested it on, except for a MacBook Pro on Chrome, where the right gray sidebar does two unwanted behaviors:

1. Too close to the left div blocks, and
2. Too thin, where the inner social icons at the bottom (see picture) don't force the width of the parent container.

The html of the gray sidebar looks like this:

```
<div class="three columns responsive valign-top background-med-gray" style="margin:0;padding:10px;">

    ...
    ...

    <div id="follow-us">
        <h2 class="TTT margin-top-20" style="text-align: center;">Follow Us</h2>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TTT"><div id="by-fb" class="social-sprite" ></div></a>             
        <a href="https://instagram.com/ttt/"><div id="by-in" class="social-sprite" ></div></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/c/TTT"><div id="by-yt" class="social-sprite" ></div></a>

    </div>

</div>
```

My social icon styles look like this:

```
div#follow-us{
display:inline-block;
bottom: 0px;
}
div.social-sprite{
    background-image:url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/social_sprite.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin:10px auto 10px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
div#by-fb{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    width:206px;
    height:41px;
    background-position:0px 0px;
}
div#by-in{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    width:206px;
    height:41px;
    background-position:-206px 0px;
}
div#by-yt{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    width:206px;
    height:41px;
    background-position:-414px 0px;
}
```

But the real problem is illustrated in the following images. In the first image, the gray sidebar (**WHAT'S HOT**) looks like I want it to look. This is how it renders in most non-mobile screens:

[image]

One of my testers reports a different behavior on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012 and later displays have a 2560-by-1600 native resolution at 227 pixels per inch), using Chrome. As you can see, the gray sidebar is too close to the left, it's too thin, and as you can see in the third graphic, for some reason the social icons break out of the side bar.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this just chrome specific on the Macbook pro, or is every other browser affected by this issue?

Comment: @phamous Only the Macbook pro Chrome. Every browser tested on pc notebooks and tablets, and even Androids and iPhone users say it looks like it's supposed to look, as in image #1, where the gray sidebar is evenly spaced off to the right, and the width is fat, with the right padding. In fact, image #1 is a screenshot from Chrome on a Lenovo.

Comment: Your code does neither provide the columns your're talking about nor anything about any margin (or other spacing) you explained is lost. Furthermore why not putting `position:relative;
    top:20px;
    width:206px;
    height:41px;` into the ***div.social-sprite*** declaration but repetitive in each seperate social link. Therefor I assume there is some issue with your code, which you did not show to us yet.

Comment: Additionally I think it may be possible that `div.social-sprite{ margin:10px auto 10px 20px; }` (the margin-right) is the culprit here. Because `margin-right: auto` can be a negative margin too and therefor break automatic width calculation of a parent element.

Comment: @Seika85 Those in-line styles were added after the fact. I will be happy to provide the code, but it was late for me, and I didn't know where to start with the code. The reason I didn't know where to start is the css is spread out over three stylesheets. I didn't think of margin:auto as something that could be negative. In any case, it sems like relatively positioned icon holder divs should push out the container div width, but I will look at that possibility.